# latex code for predefined functions in italic font

Tags: code

I know  some latex codes `\pi,\Pi,\prod` for pi.

I want to know if there is any code that gives pi/prod or for that matter any predefined code (not letters) in latex.

I want code for pi that is slightly bent towards right.

```
\documentclass[article]{amsart}

\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\topmargin -1cm
\oddsidemargin-.5cm \evensidemargin -.5cm
\usepackage[all]{xy}\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
$\pi \prod \Pi$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want code to write that operator. I am not talking about that \Lambda

Comment: Please post a MWE.

Comment: Lowercase greek mathfonts are already italic.

Comment: @Bernard Please see the edited version

Comment: @TeXnician Please see the edited version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the default font choice, you get slanted uppercase Greek letters with `\mathnormal`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\langle\mathnormal{\Lambda}\alpha,\beta\rangle=
\langle\alpha,\mathnormal{\Lambda}\beta\rangle
\]

\[
\pi\mathnormal{\Pi}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]